# Reasons and advantages to this form of sexual dimorphism

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, xenobiology

I want to have my aliens have a culture that clashes with human modern culture and one way I want to achieve this is having some extreme sexual dimorphism.

For these aliens the sexual dimorphism is such that the males are the hosts and the females are the parasites. It's alot like reverse angler fish dimorphism and this is how it works: the females are basically really small tubes with arms and attach themselves to the males' gonads; when the female does it also her immune system and everything else combines with the male's body and they become one. The females know only one thing and that is to attach to the best male and reproduce as fast as possible.

The females outnumber the males 100 to 1. There are three gonads on the male and once they are all taken the females just attach to the previous female forming long chains that look like tails.

As for gestation and birth well gestation occurs in the male once the female has been fertilized and sends the eggs to an organ to store them and then after a 80 day period the one male has a live birth and is sent through a canal through the chain of females and then after that one hundred females are born in tiny eggs. And yes the next up in line females can fertilized when a canal grows up through all of them and send the fertilization material and retrieves and births the eggs. The fertilization and birth cycles only happen once a decade as well

My question is: what kind of environment would this system work best in and what are the benefits to it?

Comment: Angler fish dimorphism works because producing sperms is less energy consuming than producing eggs. In fact males produce billions of sperms while female produce few eggs at once.

Comment: @L.Dutch but all the energy is coming from the make so wouldn't this be basically the same?

Comment: If the male has to (indirectly) put energy into making eggs, he would have much less or none for making sperms.

Comment: @L.Dutch but aren't they easier to make and they could just make one per egg, it's not like they would need any more

Comment: If 1 per egg would be enough and the billions - 1 just a waste, why no male among the entire living set of organisms has ever take this seemly brilliant path?

Comment: @L.Dutch these are aliens and not earth creatures, and the sperm does little more that change the instructional code in the eggs and active the growth cycle

Comment: Couple of questions: 1: How do gestation and birth work? 2: Do the second/third/etc females in the 'chain' also have a chance of being fertilised?

Comment: @JoeBloggs gestation occurs in the male once the female has been fertilized and sends the eggs to an organ to store them and then after a 80 day period the one male has a live birth and is sent through a canal through the chain of females and then after that one hundred females are born in tiny eggs. And yes the next up in line females can fertilized when a canal grows up through all of them and send the fertilization material and retrieves and births the eggs. The fertilization and birth cycles only happen once a decade as well

Comment: @user45751: So the male releases sperm that fertilises the eggs that then travel to a specialised storage organ in the male, followed by male pregnancy and the birth of both a live male and females in eggs?

Comment: @JoeBloggs yeah that is how it works

Comment: After your last comments it sounds more like you are swapping names.. the male is acting female and the female is acting male...

Comment: @L.Dutch I guess it does sound like that, It ment to mimic some of the stranger mating practices of the animal kingdom like anglerfish and seahorses

Comment: @L.Dutch: I think it’s more that traditional concepts of Male/female don’t really apply so much, which is fine albeit unusual to our sensibilities.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to incorporate any clarification you made in the comments. Comments can theoretically be deleted at any time and people shouldn't need to search for the rest of the question in the comments.

Comment: @Secespitus okay I did thanks for telling me

Comment: Anglerfish is symbiosis since both the male and female benefit from having offspring.

Answer (score 5):

The reason the angler fish do it is that it is so hard to find each other in the abyss.  It is lonely. But if your mate is attached to you it is easy to find her / him.

I agree the proposed switch sort of turns conventional sexes on it head.  But in a way the angler fish do what they do as a workaround: they have sensory organs which evolved in the light and under different circumstances.  In the dark they need to make it work somehow.

So too your aliens.  Your males were huge compared to their females because their very remote ancestors did battle with each other, like elephant seals.  Now that hugeness (and perhaps a different mode of feeding / getting resources that helps them get huge) comes in handy, because the parasitic female can take advantage of it.

---

You could put these things in the deep dark like the anglerfish.  Or maybe they are loose in some sort of gaseous void like a gas giant?  Or live in interminable labyrinths.   A problem is that this sort of individual isolation is in opposition to sociality and if these aliens are going to butt heads with humans they need to be social and cooperative.

Another option: in the remote past the males protected their females from being impregnated by other males and protected the females from predators. It is easier to protect the females (and easier for the females to be protected) the closer they stayed.  What you have now is the logical end to that process: maximum closeness.

Comment: Thank you this helps alot, would this maximum closeness make even more sense if every ten years they had one big mating ritual similar to the antechinus but without all the death?

Comment: Also one more question if u don't mind answering, how do you think humanity would react to these aliens mating on an individual and group level, not every individual just the layman by today's standereds, I was thinking disgust and accusing the aliens if being barbarians and sexist, what do u think?

Comment: The reason to have a mating ritual is if there is some sort of choice involved so you can pick your favorite.  If the mates are permanently attached there is no more choice involved and no need for gathering or ritual.   Probably you could not even tell they were mating when they were; they are already stuck together.   Re disgust: would humans even be able to tell they were looking at multiple individuals when they saw one of these aliens?

Comment: once they establish communication the humans would probably learn if it

Comment: @user45751 the females aren't sentient according to your OP, if humans want to whine and cry about it, the aliens can legitimately be confused and ask how they're suppose to change the very base of their reproductive system set up by evolution.